# Client side validations gem: error messages are shown twice in development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, client-side-validation

I am using the client side validations gem (v3.1.0) with Rails 3.1.1 and whenever I tab out of a form field, in my development environment every error message is displayed twice.  In my staging and production environments, they are only shown once.  This is driving me nuts and I can't figure out WHY.

A typical form field looks like this:

```
  <div class="label">
    <label for="user_first_name">First name</label>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <input class="text" data-validate="true" id="user_first_name" name="user[first_name]" size="30" type="text" />
  </div>
```

After a validation occurs:

```
<div class="label">
    <div class="field_with_errors"><div class="field_with_errors"><label for="user_first_name">First name</label></div></div>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <div class="field_with_errors"><div class="field_with_errors"><input class="text" data-validate="true" id="user_first_name" name="user[first_name]" size="30" type="text"><label for="user_first_name" class="message">can't be blank</label></div><label for="user_first_name" class="message">can't be blank</label></div>
</div>
```

I do not understand what is going on in development that is different from staging/production other than the asset pipeline getting served differently.  Has anyone else encountered this?  I have not been able to find anything on it in online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you precompile the assets? In my case, that was the problem. Simply remove the public/assets folder and validations should display only once.